# How to focus for keyboard handling on specific JPanels in a BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing

I am having some issues with regard to obtaining Widget Focus to enable keyboard handling in Panels of my Java Swing BorderLayout.  I am able to obtain Focus for the North Panel, and then my Keyboard handlers would fire.  However, if I try and request Focus for the South Panel or the Center Panel of my layout, it simply doesn't work.  The only Panel that seems to be able to obtain Focus is the North Panel.  Does anyone know why?  Is this by design of the BorderLayout?

Now, the reason why I am experimenting with trying to pickup Focus from various Panels, is that for some reason when having the Focus set to the North Panel, it seems every once in awhile the Keyboard Handlers setup to register input on certain keys seems to simply not fire.  Almost as if they were no there.  So I thought I would simply use another Panel in my layout as the Focus point for Keyboard input and see what would happen with that, and now it seems that option doesn't work either.

Anybody have any ideas here?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but without code we'll be taking wild guesses at best. Some may hit the mark, but it may be hit or miss. Why not post pertinent code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and allow us to answer well and with confidence?

Comment: Also as a side point, I'll bet that 99% of these issues would be resolved by your using Key Bindings rather than a KeyLIstener.

Comment: The short and long answer is [use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Ok, I am using Key Bindings.  It seems as if there might be a "Focus" issue here.  In my North and South Panels, I have JTextFields being used to display data.  Can an update to a JTextField inadvertantly change the Focus off of the North Panel, and I would lose ability to detect a KeyStroke?

Comment: 1. If the JTextFields are for display only and should not grab focus, then make them unfocusable. 2. I've requested pertinent code over an hour ago -- please help us here by complying.

Answer (score 1):

## NOT a direct answer, but I can't post code in the comments

> Is there a way to dump or display all the registered key bindings to validate they are not somehow getting unregistered?

I use something like...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class KeyMappings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
//              try {
//                  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
//              } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
//                  ex.printStackTrace();
//              }

                getKeyBindingsFor(new JTree());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void getKeyBindingsFor(JComponent comp) {
        System.out.println("...WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT");
        getKeyBindingsFor(comp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT));
        System.out.println("...WHEN_FOCUSED");
        getKeyBindingsFor(comp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED));
        System.out.println("...WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW");
        getKeyBindingsFor(comp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW));
    }

    public static void getKeyBindingsFor(InputMap map) {
        if (map != null) {
            KeyStroke[] keys = map.allKeys();
            if (keys != null) {
                for (KeyStroke key : keys) {
                    Object value = map.get(key);
                    System.out.println(value + " = " + key);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("[none]");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to test the various bindings for different components and look and feels

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get keyboard input from all components you can use [KeyboardFocusManager.addKeyEventDispatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html#addKeyEventDispatcher(java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher))

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.isControlDown()&&e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_R&&e.getID()==KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED){
            //Execute this code when Ctrl+R is released
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

It does appear that north will receive key events if it is [focusable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable(boolean)) therefore you can force a specific panel to have focus and recieve key events by setting all others to non-focusable. Adding a JTextField or JButton (only components tested) to the north panel breaks this.

Comment: Do you mean having a JTextField of JButton that can obtain focus, breaks the ability to have explicit focus to another panel whom I wish to have exclusive use of the Keyboard?  Does this even apply if I have the set JTextField to Noneditable?

Comment: @user1104028 Only one component can have keyboard focus at a time, this is one of the many reasons why we generally recommend the key bindings API

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Is there a way to dump or display all the registered key bindings to validate they are not somehow getting unregistered?